# How can I view cloudwatch permission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I use this command to add invoke lambda permission on cloudwatch:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name lambdaName \
  --statement-id test --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
  --principal logs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
```

what I don't understand is how I can view this permission on AWS console. I tried to look at cloudwatch but couldn't find anywhere about permission. And how can I convert it to cloudformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In console, you have to go to `Permissions` and look at `Resource-based policy`:

[image]

Comment: it is a little weird. Why the permission comes to lambda? I thought it is used to grant cloudwatch permission to invoke this lambda.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Its for lambda. Its like a bucket policy for S3 buckets.

Comment: but why is the action `lambda:InvokeFunction`? It sounds like somebody else needs permission to invoke the labmda rather than the permission of lambda.